# Understanding risks of setting nscd positive-time-to-live to a longer duration

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap, sssd

as I mentioned in [another thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/769941/building-redundancy-by-creating-multiple-nfs-mounts-to-a-single-location), I have an LDAP system supporting two dozen Linux servers. When LDAP server is down for various reasons (firewall rule changes, power outage etc), my rest of the systems became hanged.

I am hoping to build some redundancy, and stumbled upon articles on using `nscd` or `sssd` for caching logins locally.

all my servers have nscd installed, with the following settings

```
enable-cache            passwd      yes
positive-time-to-live   passwd      600
```

these are default settings. If I understood correctly, nscd caches password for 10 min for each login.

to handle unexpected ldap server downtime, I am wondering if I can increase the `positive-time-to-live` to a larger number, say a full day (86400 s).

does this give me the ability to login, within 24 hrs, when ldap server is down?

is there any risk doing this?

I saw in various threads that `sssd` serves similar purposes, although I tried it, and it broke my PAM settings and make all login "permission denied". without being able to figure out why, I decided to remove `sssd` for now (), and focus on using `nscd` instead.

all my servers run ubuntu on various LTS versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I understood correctly, nscd caches password for 10 min for each login.

No, it only caches the user information that would be found in /etc/passwd, which is generally everything *except* the password. That would be the `shadow` map – but most LDAP configurations do not use shadow; they don't reveal the password hash to nsswitch at all.

> does this give me the ability to login, within 24 hrs, when ldap server is down?

Most likely not. In nearly all setups, login through LDAP is not done through nsswitch (i.e. *not* by retrieving the password hash for local verification); it's done by PAM actively contacting the LDAP server and having it verify the password.

The only way to cache that is via PAM. If your pam_ldap module doesn't have caching built-in, the `pam_ccache` module can be inserted above it to provide something similar.

Alternatively, if you are really looking for redundancy, then **set up a second LDAP server.** Use OpenLDAP's "Syncrepl" to have it automatically replicate data (optionally even in both directions).

(It's pretty odd that your LDAP server is more susceptible to power outages than the rest of your network, but if e.g. there are multiple circuits, then place the 2nd server on the circuit that has fewer outages...)

Comment: thanks for the comments. Now I understood what that flag does. looks like `sssd` is more designed for password caching than `nscd`. For your comment on replicated LDAP servers - I already have 2 other machines running as backup LDAP, but the problem is that the switching is not automatic - I have to replace the server info manually in `/etc/ldap.conf` in each of my 2-dozen machines and restart `nscd`. is there a way to set fallback ldap in the conf file?

Comment: Re: "**It's pretty odd that your LDAP server is more susceptible to power outages than the rest**" - power outages have been rare. For the past few incidences, unexpected campus-wide firewall server/rule changes could make rest machines fail to see my ldap server. it also happened twice that the LDAP server had hard-drive failures that render the system unresponsive.

Comment: Having a single domain name that points to both LDAP servers' IP addresses would probably be one way for automatic fail over (though not the fastest – it depends on which LDAP client is being used though, and on what timeout you configure). VRRP/CARP (giving the two servers a "virtual IP") is another method if both machines are on the same subnet; probably near-instant.